# Choosing A file from explorer and insert his name to the script

Tags: windows, file, powershell, explorer

Im writing a script that has a textbox. The user clicks it and windows explorer opens. I want the user to double click a file and when he does that the name of the file will be written in the textbox, so I can use this to continue with the script.
Cant find an answer on how to do that.
So **how can i pick a file from explorer and insert its name to a textbox?**
thank for your help, Ofir.

Comment: Anything wrong with the [open file dialog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2009/09/01/hey-scripting-guy-can-i-open-a-file-dialog-box-with-windows-powershell/) ?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |  Out-Null

Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{   
 [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") |
 Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
 $OpenFileDialog.Title = "Choose a file"
 $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
 $OpenFileDialog.filter = "Text files (*.txt)| *.txt"
 $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
 $OpenFileDialog.filename
 }

$Form1 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
$Form1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(400,370)


$InputBox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$InputBox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(51,219)
$InputBox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(220,310)
$InputBox3.Multiline= $false
$Form1.Controls.Add($InputBox3)

$InputBox3.Add_Click({$InputBox3.Text = Get-FileName -initialDirectory "c:\temp"});

$Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Actually I see it inserts the whole path, I only want the name of the file, any idea how to make it take the name and not the path?

Comment: Use `Split-Path $path -Leaf`